# How to get top rated posts using wp query?

Tags: wp-query, comment-form, comment-meta

I want to get top rated posts using wp query. The rating value is store in comment meta database table when some one post a comment on wp post or cpt.Please screenshot

[image]

**EDIT**
Here is my code

```
add_action( 'comment_form_top', 'wpcr_change_comment_form_defaults');
function wpcr_change_comment_form_defaults( ) {


    $star1_title = __('Very bad', 'post-rating');
    $star2_title = __('Bad', 'post-rating');
    $star3_title = __('Meh', 'post-rating');
    $star4_title = __('Pretty good', 'post-rating');
    $star5_title = __('Rocks!', 'post-rating');


    echo '<fieldset class="rating">
    <legend>Rating<span class="required">*</span></legend>
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5" title="'.$star5_title.'">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4" title="'.$star4_title.'">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="'.$star3_title.'">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2" title="'.$star2_title.'">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1" title="'.$star1_title.'">1 star</label>
    </fieldset>';

}
//////// save comment meta data ////////
add_action( 'comment_post', 'wpcr_save_comment_meta_data' );

function wpcr_save_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ) {
    $rating =  (empty($_POST['rating'])) ? FALSE : $_POST['rating'];
    add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'rating', $rating );
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of how you're handling the stars right now?

Comment: Is that rating field coming from some plugin?

Comment: No, I am using custom code to add star rating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry. I have found solution for your issue. you can use below code to display 5 top rated posts based on average rating. i have created below function to get top average rated post using sql queries and wp_query functions.

here is updated function for all custom post type.

```
function top_rated_post_via_comment_of_CPT($post_per_page = 5){
 global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT(wp_comments.comment_post_ID), GROUP_CONCAT(wp_comments.comment_iD separator ', ') comment_ids FROM wp_comments JOIN wp_commentmeta ON wp_commentmeta.comment_id = wp_comments.comment_ID GROUP BY wp_comments.comment_post_ID", ARRAY_A);


    foreach($results as $key => $value) {

        $c_post_id = $value['comment_post_ID'];
        $comment_ids = $value['comment_ids'];
        $res = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT AVG(`meta_value`) as avg_rate FROM wp_commentmeta WHERE `meta_key` = 'rating' AND comment_ID IN ($comment_ids) ORDER BY meta_value" );
       $results[$key]['avg_rate'] = $res[0]->avg_rate;
    }
    # sort value by high rated
    $avg_rate = array_column($results, 'avg_rate');
    array_multisort($avg_rate, SORT_DESC, $results);

    $top_rated = array();
    foreach ($results as $result) {

        if($result['avg_rate'] && $result['comment_ids'] )
        {
            $top_rated[] = $result['comment_post_ID'];
        }
    }

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array("post","movies"),
        'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
        'post__in' => $top_rated,
        'orderby' => 'post__in' 
    );

    $top_rated_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $top_rated_posts->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';

        while ( $top_rated_posts->have_posts() ) {
            $top_rated_posts->the_post();
            $new_key = array_search(get_the_id(), array_column($results, 'comment_post_ID'));
            echo '<li>Post Name : ' . get_the_title() . ' | Average Rate :'.number_format((float)$results[$new_key]['avg_rate'], 2, '.', '').'</li>';

        }
        echo '</ul>';

        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }
}
```

**echo top_rated_post_via_comment_of_CPT(5);**

to add Average column in admin post listing dashboard

```
 add_filter( 'manage_movies_posts_columns', 'set_custom_edit_columns' );
    add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'set_custom_edit_columns' );
    function set_custom_edit_columns($columns) {
        $columns['avg_rate'] = __( 'Average Rate', 'your_text_domain' );
        return $columns;
    }

// Add the data to the custom columns for the book post type:
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_column', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'manage_movies_custom_column' , 'custom_column', 10, 2 );
function custom_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {

        case 'avg_rate' :
            global  $wpdb;
            $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT(wp_comments.comment_post_ID), GROUP_CONCAT(wp_comments.comment_iD separator ', ') comment_ids FROM wp_comments JOIN wp_commentmeta ON wp_commentmeta.comment_id = wp_comments.comment_ID GROUP BY wp_comments.comment_post_ID", ARRAY_A);
            foreach($results as $key => $value) {

                $c_post_id = $value['comment_post_ID'];
                $comment_ids = $value['comment_ids'];
                $res = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT AVG(`meta_value`) as avg_rate FROM wp_commentmeta WHERE `meta_key` = 'rating' AND comment_ID IN ($comment_ids) ORDER BY meta_value" );
               $results[$key]['avg_rate'] = $res[0]->avg_rate;
            }
            $new_key = array_search($post_id, array_column($results, 'comment_post_ID'));
            if($results[$new_key]['avg_rate']){
            echo number_format((float)$results[$new_key]['avg_rate'], 2, '.', '');
            }
            else
            {
                echo "No rating";
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

i hope this function can solve you query. let me know if this function helps you!

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. I'll test this code and then contact you soon.

Comment: okay. let me know if any confusion.

Comment: Sql query returns an empty array.Average rating is shown as 0.00.

Comment: i have queries. do you have any rated posts ? is wp_ your table prefix ? if not then you have to change prefix in code to your table prefix. because i have used your comment form and comment meta and develop this function to get top average rated posts. t have tested and it is working.

Comment: Yes, I have 2 rated posts. And also I change tabel prefix and getting only one rated posts with correct average.

Comment: Does it will not return "Hello World" default post if this post also have some average rating?

Comment: i have made some changes in sql query and update the answer. please check now. let me know if any issue.

Comment: Ok.I'll test.What about cpt( like movie) if I want to show just cpt top rated posts?

Comment: WP_Query is not working properly.

Comment: i have add new function for CPT top average rated posts in answer. can you please tell me what kind of issue you are facing ?

Comment: I have 3 default posts and one cpt post. WP_Query args return 4 ids but wp query loop returns only 3 (default) posts ,not cpt post.

Comment: okay. because wp_query return by default "post" post type if you did not pass "post_type" argument in wp_query. if you want to get all custom post type you can do using pass this in wp_query arg **'post_type' => array("post","movies","CPT2","CPT3"),** got it?

Comment: Yes.Thanks.Does this function also works for admin posts column? Means if i also want to show avg rating in post admin custom column(column name like"Average").

Comment: I have add code for display average rating column in admin post listing column. please check my updated answer. Did my function solved your queries? please let me know.

Comment: Default "Hello world" post have 3.25 avg, but in admin column, code showing "no rating", others are showing correct avg.

Comment: okay. i have made minor change in condition. now it will work in admin column also. just replace **if($new_key){** with **if($results[$new_key]['avg_rate']){**. now every things working fine.

Comment: Thanks man. Every thing is working perfect now. Thanks again for sharing your time with me!

Comment: your welcome :-)

Comment: Hi, How to create shortcodes of these functions?